# Two way data synchronization between web application and REST API server

Tags: design, web-development, rest, performance, synchronization

I have a web application and a REST API server (Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016) that I don't have access to it's code, but I have access to the available resources. I need to create a data sync between both servers, some of the tables are one way and the others two way data sync has to be done, I haven't found any good solution to solve the problem.

I can handle the one way data sync by creating a log table of each SQL statement executed in my web application, and after a period of time I can use the REST API endpoints to sync data from my web application into the REST API server, but how to do the inverse (i.e sync data from REST API application into my web application)?

The naive solution are to get all table records from REST API server and then start syncing by comparing records from both sources, given that I currently don't have timestamp on the records, and I have no way to get the resources that are modified/inserted from the REST Server, because of that I should get all the resources from REST server and not the changed records which will increase the network traffic during every sync operation.

Insertion are not a problem, the problem is with update and delete operations.

Comment: Look into Dynamics 365 change tracking which will allow you to query only for records updated since the last time you checked.

Answer (score 1):

Given the scenario where you can't control/access REST server, you have to make calls for every table until REST service expose some API to enable this feature. But off-course you can optimize data flowing through network:

1. Create list of tables which have updates more recent than your service (by querying REST service).
2. Now only sync tables from above list.

or,

Try to fetch updated/new data in one call (in step 1).

In my opinion above solutions are not fundamentally different from your current solution but they do try to control amount of traffic in network. You have to implement both and run load test on them to see what fits best.

Comment: step 1 is too abstract could you explain please?

Comment: @M.Abulsoud step 1 comes from same step as you are currently doing. syncing up tables at your side and on REST side. instead of full table sync just fire queries like are there any updates on table T1 since you last synced. in this way you will be able to reduce traffic.

Comment: ok, I handle what you said by create a flag in the history table called pending if the record  not synced for x value in time then it's value 'Y', and after finishing the syc I will change it's value to 'N' so that I will reduce the sync traffic from my side (number of requests going to the API server). Actually it's not hard for insert to handle the two way sync, but for update I cannot find a solution for it since the rest api is using odata protocol to represent the resources, I don't have a timestamp attribute in the resources but some of the resources has ETAG attribute.

Comment: Do you know how to compare records to check what record must win in update operation if I don't have the timestamp is that possible?

Comment: If you dont have information like insert or updated timestamp, this would be difficult to implement. Are you taking full data back up from REST, currently?

Comment: Actually I don't right any line of code I want to find the correct solution first, but If you mean, I got all records for a specific resource from the REST and store them in my app then no, I was try figure out a way to get the change log for a specific entity/resource from the CRM REST API documentation, I founded this API RetrieveAuditPartitionList Function
Which Retrieves the list of database partitions that are used to store audited history data, but currently I'm not able to test this api endoint from the source REST CRM app.

Comment: Cant comment on proprietary api's. my comments were related to any services developed internally by teams. For these kind of solutions its better to ask their support or post in user mailing list.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have create a proposed solution if you want to check I can send it for you.

Comment: sure, I would love to see the approach.

Comment: I cannot get the deleted records from the CRM side, I think it's impossible to handle the delete operations. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: the crux of trick would be so see which data is present in your service but not in REST. Those will be the deleted records since your last sync.